# Como executar um javascript, utilizando href?

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de executar o javascript a baixo utilizando **href**.
Mas ao clicar no suposto link *Log Out*, nada acontece. Se mantenho o cursor em cima do link ele me mostra o destino como `javascript:logout()`

```js
function logout() {
    var choose = confirm("Deseja realmente sair?");
    if (choose == true) {
        location="Main.html";
    } else {
   
    }
```

```html
<nav id="menuOp"> 
    <a href="javascript:logout()">Log Out</a></br>
    <b>Olá, #</b>
</nav>
```

Comment: Você tem mesmo que utilizar o href? Por qual motivo?

Comment: Quando um código em javascript não funcionar, abra o console do navegador e veja se o mesmo imprime alguma mensagem de erro. Se o que aconteceu foi o que o @JoaoPaulo disse, provavelmente allgum erro foi cuspido no console e você nem precisaria ter criado essa pergunta...

Comment: Voce a abriu `function logout() {` mas nao fechou com `}`, e um erro de digitação.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No seu script faltou fechar a função logout

```
logout(){ 
   //conteudo
}
```

Também pode trocar o href por onclick:

```
<a onclick="javascript:logout()">Log Out</a>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por ver esse erro que passou despercebido e pela dica do onclick